# cant retrieve data from firebase realtime in ASP.NET webforms C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase-realtime-database, webforms

I have login page in ASP.NET webforms using C#.

What I've tried is - this is my admin account model:

```
public class AdminAccount
{
    public int Idno { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Mname { get; set; }
    public string Bdate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string WRS_Name { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public string Proof { get; set; }
}
```

My `account.aspx.cs`:

```
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the email and password entered by the user
    string username = txt_username.Text;
    string password = txt_password.Text;

    // Check if the email and password are valid
    FirebaseResponse response;
    response = twoBigDB.Get("ADMIN/" + username);
       
    Model.AdminAccount obj = response.ResultAs<Model.AdminAccount>();
       
    if (obj.Username == username && obj.Pass == password)
    {
        Session["username"] = username;
        Session["password"] = password;
        Session["WRSname"] = obj.WRS_Name;

        // Login successful, redirect to admin homepage
        Response.Redirect("/Admin/AdminIndex.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid username or password');</script>");
    }
}
```

My expected output is inside my if condition would be true, Username can fetch data from firebase realtime and with username input by the user.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the if-statement and check the variables. What do you see?

Comment: Note: Don't store plaintext-passwords in databases. Use hashes instead. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: This is line `response = twoBigDB.Get("ADMIN/" + username);` is needed to be inspected.